# react-redux flow type definitions for ownProps, mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, flowtype

I'm a newbie using flow so I might be doing some very stupid mistakes.

I want to create a Props flow type that intersects the props passed to a component, the props obtained from a redux store returned from mapStateToProps and some action creators defined on mapDispatchToProps.

All the code shown below is available on this [flow try](https://flow.org/try/#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-P9ThWLxwMg6D-UDYMwxleDFlzGIEBkCMFS8PUfEQGQ+BKeRik3UpPjAajTR0GkBiMbxhlzMiowqYjSIIsAADIwGQ-9eFE8TXxQuNFjZXAyxYmQYDIcQpDtQgziUwhxBDOANBgN8Q3wDoSBkOA8wkOUFkFKE+QoAjsjEPiKJ8CpWLouQQm88kVFYlFGRaABmJRVAlF0il+Rj5H8iKTSC7JQuYjhU3jeFERc2MNnTRMclS9K8sRFpxzjYrdhaLM2S4AyjJMsySAnbxvTAJzI1KsA3OjDyWJI2jYp8+4gTyDgxrGiwYgAaTAABaMA5CkczFSMWywCkSDkpCjgfA4QLtDELaFHG8bJpm+bFuW6y1o24bvmCThnSBQ6UpOjgLDiaa5v0wzjLAQw1kcVb5jG3bnSC4IRuOk6Pq++bat+t8Aea4GJB2io0vKhMsrK3LsaTfJ3qwOGFqWj9rvmdbIKK-HWl2mnMsq3HYVppkibAT7zp++r-qaoGbJB3aoHwABrIhUIynY+3nS5WBMU6sE576EZ55H+dsnaeJrX0PykGYXzIrwKlYXxOC8waGOkeRwv29i9EGcKnu+S2mMe90Do4tFjE4BmM2yo5NQl8Lffyzr9iC+30UDuMlF8YZUCAA).

Let's consider that I have the following State and action creators:

## State and Action Creators

```
// State type
type State = {
    state_text: string,
    state_num: number,
}

// Action type
type Action = 
    | { type: 'ACTION_CREATOR_1', text: string}
    | { type: 'ACTION_CREATOR_2', value: number}


// action creators
const actionCreator_1 = (): Action => ({
    type: 'ACTION_CREATOR_1',
    text: 'some text',
})
const actionCreator_2 = (num: number): Action => ({
    type: 'ACTION_CREATOR_2',
    value: num + 1,
})
```

I followed an example on [this](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4002#issuecomment-344255679) post, and I came to something like the following to define my types:

## Prop type definition

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: State) => {
    const { state_text, state_num } = state
    return { state_text, state_num }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    actionCreator_1,
    actionCreator_2,
}


// type extract return helper
type _ExtractReturn<B, F: (...args: any[]) => B> = B
type ExtractReturn<F> = _ExtractReturn<*, F>
  

// set combined types 
type ReduxState = ExtractReturn<typeof mapStateToProps>

type ReduxActions = typeof mapDispatchToProps

type OwnProps = { 
    own_string: string,
    own_num: number 
}

type Props =  OwnProps & ReduxState & ReduxActions
```

With this definition, I was expecting Props to be something like this:

```
type DesiredProp =   {|
    own_string: string,
    own_num: number,
    state_text: string,
    state_num: number,
    actionCreator_1: () => Action,
    actionCreator_2: (num: number) => Action,
|}
```

However, the following situation shows no flow errors:

```
const props2: Props = {
    own_string: 'text',                 // OK - gives error if 123  
    own_num: 123,                       // OK - gives error if 'text'
    state_text: 123,                    // NOK - should be an error     
    state_num: 'text',                  // NOK - should be an error 
    actionCreator_1: actionCreator_1,   // OK - gives error if actionCreator_2
    actionCreator_2: actionCreator_1,   // NOK - should be an error 
    fakeActionCreator: () => {}         // NOK - should be an error 
}
```

I put all this code in this [flow try](https://flow.org/try/#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-P9ThWLxwMg6D-UDYMwxleDFlzGIEBkCMFS8PUfEQGQ+BKeRik3UpPjAajTR0GkBiMbxhlzMiowqYjSIIsAADIwGQ-9eFE8TXxQuNFjZXAyxYmQYDIcQpDtQgziUwhxBDOANBgN8Q3wDoSBkOA8wkOUFkFKE+QoAjsjEPiKJ8CpWLouQQm88kVFYlFGRaABmJRVAlF0il+Rj5H8iKTSC7JQuYjhU3jeFERc2MNnTRMclS9K8sRFpxzjYrdhaLM2S4AyjJMsySAnbxvTAJzI1KsA3OjDyWJI2jYp8+4gTyDgxrGiwYgAaTAABaMA5CkczFSMWywCkSDkpCjgfA4QLtDELaFHG8bJpm+bFuW6y1o24bvmCThnSBQ6UpOjgLDiaa5v0wzjLAQw1kcVb5jG3bnSC4IRuOk6Pq++bat+t8Aea4GJB2io0vKhMsrK3LsaTfJ3qwOGFqWj9rvmdbIKK-HWl2mnMsq3HYVppkibAT7zp++r-qaoGbJB3aoHwABrIhUIynY+3nS5WBMU6sE576EZ55H+dsnaeJrX0PykGYXzIrwKlYXxOC8waGOkeRwv29i9EGcKnu+S2mMe90Do4tFjE4BmM2yo5NQl8Lffyzr9iC+30UDuMlF8YZUCAA) to make it easier to understand and play with.

How can I achieve what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it looks like you have a few things topics in your post, so I'll break up my answer

## Returning a Disjoint Union Member

Here you're returning a member of the `Action` [disjoint union](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-disjoint-unions)

```
// Action type
type Action = 
  | { type: 'ACTION_CREATOR_1', text: string}
  | { type: 'ACTION_CREATOR_2', value: number}

// action creators
const actionCreator_1 = (): Action => ({
  type: 'ACTION_CREATOR_1',
  text: 'some text',
})

const actionCreator_2 = (num: number): Action => ({
  type: 'ACTION_CREATOR_2',
  value: num + 1,
})
```

And you expect it to be able to typecheck these lines:

```
actionCreator_1: actionCreator_1,   // OK - gives error if actionCreator_2
actionCreator_2: actionCreator_1,   // NOK - should be an error
```

The thing is, you set the return type for the action creators to both be `Action`, so as long as one of your actionCreator_1/2 properties returns an `Action`, the code is correct. What you need to do here is to make the return type of the action creators more specific:

```
type Action1 = { type: 'ACTION_CREATOR_1', text: string}
type Action2 = { type: 'ACTION_CREATOR_2', value: number}

// Action type
type Action = 
  | Action1
  | Action2

// action creators
const actionCreator_1 = (): Action1 => ({
  type: 'ACTION_CREATOR_1',
  text: 'some text',
})

const actionCreator_2 = (num: number): Action2 => ({
  type: 'ACTION_CREATOR_2',
  value: num + 1,
})
```

And now flow will throw an error ([try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVxhgMoBcCGuApmLgJ4AORq5VOBxYAvGAN6oCQAzg0QPrEAHrgBcYHgCcAlgDsA5gBpUYbrz4yArgFsxmrQCMiEpQF90tEgEEAxrilwZARmZtSlImIDklgMIAVAEkAeQA5Ph8AJQBRSz8giL5HTwVSImExSVk5MwswGzsHACYXVjcqL19A0PDo2Pi+QuSwADd8GA0PMD1DCTMMLHz7GTLqXMGHF2UwAB882yHHVFnxmUL0TDB8eYnrCSJCOAkuVGsHHk3tmR89g4lElwAKAEoxFecmAD4wB-YwEYr-MEwpEYnEEkklH8hKIwJ4uHAtCRoclUCYnuhTjJzlsClcbrhDg1HnpdNoei85rjip9vr9-rDKkCaqD6o1IS02h1SVowABqMCOUzo9DrLA+BEUBxEGS4MBTE5nWVafAUPCEIh+OAABQkcAoXEePHVYjVxCezC+dMx51KRuIAjSuBSdv4ejAJhcLqme1wGgkw1tamhzrUbrMfWtSpVABEpFwKIRrAALTU6vUGlh0nFDa77Al3QVTbMOXO3BqmEUbXKOiQ4sA+v3DJNEGBUCQ0dxgPhRYS12wRIi+-0AHgAQikAGJiB4AOjn+Akci4YnwMjIAG0ALrmmmjr4sUcdug93B93ADocyYcT-ddk9ni+N4cgScfeX9cSDsCnAyyIgAExGA0jxIAd-w0QRTRIFh7xxR8RwsOAoDAZVVV4VNdX1N9cjAiCVgzEYkJQmM4wTXBkww9MQLAIIEBkNN9RKOU-kQGQ+EyeQMlPLJ2VY9RtG5Ho5T6XIGIImi6LEsAADIwFwyDeBkuSALwy5jg-XBmzABwYDIcQpF9QghlIJNCHEJM4A0GBANM5oSBkOAwCMXUjgVLFZQoTCuEcMQpMzKYWLo9juM42EOLkFE-g4PiSQFQoAGYlFUdUHXSMKQoi9lkvtWLHASrLizxPNCR8i5cVLfNEgKy4KsJQoVxq-E6orD8uAsqybPwOzNmGNzzk89N6rAPy2AC7SgvCrxkQUDhZtmjYggAaTAABaMA5CkOyDWcw4wCkZC8vijgpmioLcvyua5oW5a1o2ranIkFy9uQzxkU4F1UphQ6ZsujYQiW1bzMs6ywEMHqHpc2aTo+2LXsdZJLo4P6AbWtrgcAsHVwhw5jqiwraoLBryqagsUiRrAUfWzaiG2x7dv2sqcxJhoTvx5mhrZ4rSfJsB-puoGOtBkgsZ2iRcZUKB8AAayIFYCenHdLRMK6sD5wG0cFzHhlF46RM7aMaakPZ-wYlw-lYaZOD4ybxAypKYoEroySMJKPuhLjpHkV3Q0d7oXc4Tmy1K54LUpIYksDyqhoeWK-YkRWw4cJRpj6VAgA)):

```
    76:     actionCreator_2: actionCreator_1,   // NOK - should be an error 
                            ^ Cannot assign object literal to `props2` because property `value` is missing in `Action1` [1] but exists in `Action2` [2] in the return value of property `actionCreator_2`.
    References:
    18: const actionCreator_1 = (): Action1 => ({
                                    ^ [1]
    23: const actionCreator_2 = (num: number): Action2 => ({
                                               ^ [2]
    76:     actionCreator_2: actionCreator_1,   // NOK - should be an error 
                            ^ Cannot assign object literal to `props2` because string literal `ACTION_CREATOR_1` [1] is incompatible with string literal `ACTION_CREATOR_2` [2] in property `type` of the return value of property `actionCreator_2`.
    References:
    9: type Action1 = { type: 'ACTION_CREATOR_1', text: string}
                              ^ [1]
    10: type Action2 = { type: 'ACTION_CREATOR_2', value: number}
                               ^ [2]
```

## [Exactly](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types) Specifying an Object

Right now you're taking an intersection of three objects to get your `Props` type. Since you're working with an inexact object (the result of the intersection), you don't get an exact result. First you need to adjust your `OwnProps` to be exact. Then you need to combine all the objects. I do this with a spread:

```
// set combined types 
type ReduxState = ExtractReturn<typeof mapStateToProps>
type ReduxActions = typeof mapDispatchToProps

// This object type needs to be exact
type OwnProps = {|
  own_string: string,
  own_num: number 
|}

// Use a spread to combine the exact objects into one
type Props =  {|
  ...OwnProps,
  ...ReduxState,
  ...ReduxActions,
|}
```

And now it throws an error for that pesky extra property ([try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVxhgMoBcCGuApmLgJ4AORq5VOBxYAvGAN6oCQAzg0QPrEAHrgBcYHgCcAlgDsA5gBpUYbrz4yArgFsxmrQCMiEpQF90tEgEEAxrilwZARmZtSlImIDklgMIAVAEkAeQA5Ph8AJQBRSz8giL5HTwVSImExSVk5MwswGzsHACYXVjcqL19A0PDo2Pi+QuSwADd8GA0PMD1DCTMMLHz7GTLqXMGHF2UwAB882yHHVFnxmUL0TDB8eYnrCSJCOAkuVGsHHk3tmR89g4lElwAKAEoxFecmAD4wB-YwEYr-MEwpEYnEEkklH8hKIwJ4uHAtCRoclUCYnuhTjJzlsClcbrhDg1HnpdNoei85rjip9vr9-rDKkCaqD6o1IS02h1SVowABqMCOUzo9DrLA+BEUBxEGS4MBTE5nWVafAUPCEIh+OAABQkcAoXEePHVYjVxCezC+dMx51KRuIAjSuBSdv4ejAJhcLqme1wGgkw1tamhzrUbrMfWtSpVABEpFwKIRrAALTU6vUGlh0nFDa77Al3QVTbMOXO3BqmEUbXKOiQ4sA+v3DJNEGBUCQ0dxgPhRYS12wRIi+-0AHgAQikAGJiB4AOjn+Akci4YnwMjIAG0ALrmmmjr4sUcdug93B93ADocyYcT-ddk9ni+N4cgScfeVTP4bLiDsCnAyyIgABMRgND8RjAAdAI0QRTRIFh7xxR8RwsOAoDAZVVV4VNdX1N8-ihTtIOglYMxGVD0JjOME1wZNsPTMDciCBAZDTfUSmmMC-kQGQ+EyeQMlPLJ2XwsBuPUbRuR6OUROmPoRNyVjSLYDiRL+OcZyYlicK4YT8PUoiYN4XS1LnAySN02TRVIZtRJkGAyHEKRfUIIZrMIcQkzgDQYGApN8GaEgZDgMAjF1I4FSxWUKG0xwxEUkowLEvi5C8ZKUT+DgxJJAVCgAZiUVR1QddJYTS9lCvtbLHDy8rizxPNCVii5cVLfNElqy5WsJQoV06-FuorfoPK8nywD8gLNmGCLzmi9MerAeLM0S5jeME-jYWRBQOG27aNiCABpMAAFowDkKQAoNULDjAKQ0Oq3KOCmTKVqqmqdp2vbDpOs6LpCiQwputDPGRTgXWKmF7q296NhCA7juG7zgMMSa-rC7anrB7LgcdZJ3o4GG4ZOrhPMRsBkdXVHDkejK6q6gtepa-qCxSfGsEJ07zqIS7-uu27mpzJmGie2nBfmkWGuZ1mwFhr6EdG8nhiuiRqZUKB8AAayIFY6enHdLRMD6sBl+HiZGpGSAppXHr6XJoy5qQ9kA1iXD+VgOOenjkoE6R5AKrKJK6MkjAKsHoW9oTQdDAPumDzhxbLJrngtSkhgK+O2vmh5spjiQ9ZThwlEs9AgA)):

```
    74: const props2: Props = {                          ^ Cannot assign object literal to `props2` because property `fakeActionCreator` is missing in `Props` [1] but exists in object literal [2].
    References:
    74: const props2: Props = {
                      ^ [1]
    74: const props2: Props = {                          ^ [2]
```

## Extracted Type Interfering with Inference

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get flow to understand the return type of your `ReduxState` through return type extraction. It seems to think it's this:

```
type ReduxState = ExtractReturn<(state: State) => {|state_num: (string | number), state_text: (string | number)|}>
```

So it seems to be merging the inference from your usage in the `props2` object and the extracted type information. To get around this, my best advice would be to manually type the `mapStateToProps` function's output:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: State): {|
    state_text: string,
    state_num: number,
|} => {
  const { state_text, state_num } = state
  return { state_text, state_num }
}
```

After which it should throw an error ([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVxhgMoBcCGuApmLgJ4AORq5VOBxYAvGAN6oCQAzg0QPrEAHrgBcYHgCcAlgDsA5gBpUYbrz4yArgFsxmrQCMiEpQF90tEgEEAxrilwZARmZtSlImIDklgMIAVAEkAeQA5Ph8AJQBRSz8giL5HTwVSImExSVk5MwswGzsHACYXVjcqL19A0PDo2Pi+QuSwADd8GA0PMD1DCTMMLHz7GTLqXMGHF2UwAB882yHHVFnxmUL0TDB8eYnrCSJCOAkuVGsHHk3tmR89g4lElwAKAEoxFecmAD4wB-YwEYr-MEwpEYnEEkklH8hKIwJ4uHAtCRoclUCYnuhTjJzlsClcbrhDg1HnpdNoei85rjip9vr9-rDKkCaqD6o1IS02h1SVowABqMCOUzo9DrLA+BEUBxEGS4MBTE5nWVafAUPCEIh+OAABQkcAoXEePHVYjVxAprGmnCNxAEaRhmXk7L+1v4JK6ZKMSmmJmYXzpmPOpRdtuEKWDejAPpYLqme1wGgkwyDamhYbUEbMfQDSpVABEpFwKIRrAALTU6vUGlh0nFDa77Al3QVTWsOeu3BqmEUbXJ2iQ4sBxhPDEtEGBUCQ0dxgPhRYT92wRIjxxMAHgAQikAGJiB4AOgP+Akci4YnwMjIAG0ALpPX1gddfFjrqd0Oe4Be4JcrmSrrdPmd30-b9h1XEBtw+eV+nEZcwFOAxZCIAATEYDVfEglyQjRBFNEgWCAnEQLXCw4CgMBlVVXhy11fVINyTDsJWKsRlI8i8wLItcFLajK3QsAggQGQK31EpLT+RAZD4B05AyD8snZCT1G0bkejlb1zGnYTmLYMSwAPPcBKEmiuHZfSGJw3hTIPcymK9Poe1HMAHBgMhxCkeNCCGUgS0IcQSzgDQYBQnzmhIGQ4DAIxdSOBUsVlChjMcMQtJKKZxMEqS5PkLxpJRP4OEUt1HEKABmJRVHVEMYThLK5DylRw2UgVSvZDhWzxBtCSSi5cXbRtEla9q+sJQoz0uYa7kKLtoK4fzAuC-BQs2YZYvOBLK1GsAUurNKnIy6SvGRBQOBOk6NiCABpMAAFowDkKRQoNKLDjAKQyOKkqOCmAqMqKlrTtO86rtu+7HsiiRotesjPGRK0UztMQPuOgGNhCS6br8gKgrAQxlvB6KTu+xqdFhI6AY4VH0du2asZQ3Hz3xw4vvyob8S6sberZpsUgprAqbuh6iCeiGXrenq6y5hpvtZzrJo5iXZYG3mwDR4HMfmnGSAZ56JGZlQoHwABrIgVgm3c7xpVgTEBrBVYxmmNfp4Yda+vpclzIWpD2JDhJcP4LU4RSDvEWrysKpruk9OHKuhWTpEdaObTdSPjE4GWO26557xWcr0-6zaHmTj0JAtr4c6WPpUCAA))

```
    80:     state_text: 123,                    // NOK - should be an error     
                     ^ Cannot assign object literal to `props2` because number [1] is incompatible with string [2] in property `state_text`.
    References:
    80:     state_text: 123,                    // NOK - should be an error     
                     ^ [1]
    34:     state_text: string,
                     ^ [2]
    81:     state_num: 'text',                  // NOK - should be an error 
                      ^ Cannot assign object literal to `props2` because string [1] is incompatible with number [2] in property `state_num`.
    References:
    81:     state_num: 'text',                  // NOK - should be an error 
                      ^ [1]
    35:     state_num: number,
                       ^ [2]
```

Comment: Thanks! you just answered all my questions! :) Flow is not so intuitive as it initially seems, but I'm starting to get used to it and to like it.